# Colspan modification dependent on CSS3 @media Query

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a responsive table on my web page. This table contains three columns and a lot of rows. However, some rows contain only one column with colspan 3.

I need to have a table with two additional columns for large screens only so I need to modify colspan to 5.

Small and medium screens

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+
| xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Large screens - what I have

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Large screens - what I want to have

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |  xxxxx  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

It is not possible to modify colspan in CSS and it is not possible to have @media Queries from CSS in JavaScript.
I don't want to have break points definiton in two places in my code. Additionaly, in JavaScript there is a problem with correct recognization of screen width because of scroll bars and different browser implementation of this (it may not corespond with the CSS break points, read more [here](http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries)).

Is there any possibility how to achieve this with CSS break points only? I need to have my design mobile first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do that with JavaScript. What you only need is to have some class which adds some specific CSS to your element for your media query. Then you can detect changes of CSS by JavaScript and change the colspan. (inspiration has been taken [here](http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries))

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
  // run test on initial page load
  checkSize();

  // run test on resize of the window
  $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

// detect media query by css
function checkSize(){
  if ($('td.large-only').css('display') === 'table-cell' ) {
    $('td[colspan]').attr('colspan', '5');
    $('td[colspan]').text('Colspan: 5');
  } else {
    $('td[colspan]').attr('colspan', '3');
    $('td[colspan]').text('Colspan: 3');
  }
}
```

```css
table td {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

table td[colspan] {
  background: #5CAD5C;
}

table td.large-only {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  table td.large-only {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[CodePen link](http://codepen.io/Akarienta/pen/vEdaYp)

Answer (score 7):

If you move borders from your `table` to your `td`s, you can use a constant 5 for your colspan.  It won't create extra columns.

Changes to CSS:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

**Snippet 1**

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

table td[colspan] {
  background: #5CAD5C;
}

table td[colspan]::before {
  content:"3 columns, colspan=5";
}

table td.large-only {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  table td.large-only {
    display: table-cell;
  }

  table td[colspan]::before {
    content:"5 columns, colspan=5";
  }  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Snippet 2**

Since you want to maintain the `colspan` = 3 or 5, you can do that with a media query:

Updated HTML:

```
<td colspan="3">colspan=3</td>
<td colspan="5">colspan=5</td>
```

Updated CSS:

```
table td.large-only, table td[colspan="5"] {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  table td.large-only, table td[colspan="3"] {
    display: none;
  }

  table td.large-only, table td[colspan="5"] {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

table td[colspan] {
  background: #5CAD5C;
}

table td.large-only, table td[colspan="5"] {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  table td.large-only {
    display: table-cell;
  }

  table td[colspan="3"] {
    display: none;
  }

  table td[colspan="5"] {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">colspan=3</td>
    <td colspan="5">colspan=5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="large-only">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="large-only">4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Of course but if you are using some front-end framework, e.g. ZURB Foundation, and you want to use the default settings this is not applicable. Also if you need borders for some other reason you can't use it this way. My solutin is more generally.

Comment: Gotcha.  I've added a new Snippet, which uses media queries to handle the colspan.

Comment: Sure, that's another solution but I don't like it because of code duplicity. You can have very complex table generation and it can be a problem because of maintainability and also data transfer because it may load your data two times - it may cause delay in page loading.